# C++ Embedded Python and create_string_buffer

Tags: python, c++, arrays, buffer

I'm a newbie in Python and embedding it too. And I have one problem:

There is function in my python module that recieves buffer created with **ctypes.create_string_buffer(size)** and fills it by content from some memory address:

```
def get_mem(self, address, size, data):
    self.mem.read_ram_block(address, size, data)
```

How should I call this method with using of **(char *)** buffer? I want fill my C++ buffer with recieved from python.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more. It's not perfectly clear for me what you're asking and what you'd like to achieve.

Comment: Function "get_mem" should recieve "data", which should be created with "ctypes.create_string_buffer(size)" function from C++. But I don't know, how to create such buffer from C++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to call the Python function `ctypes.create_string_buffer(size)`, you could easily mirror the Python coding on the C++ side:

```
static PyObject* create_string_buffer(unsigned long size) {
  PyObject *ctypes = PyImport_ImportModule("ctypes");
  if (!ctypes) return 0;
  PyObject *buf = PyObject_CallMethod(ctypes, "create_string_buffer", "k", size);
  Py_DECREF(ctypes);
  return buf;
}
```

If you'd like to use another type than `unsigned long` for the size, you'd need to change the `format` in [PyObject_CallMethod](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_CallMethod) as well. For example `O` is used for `PyObject*`. For a complete list of formats see the documentation for [Building values](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/arg.html#building-values).